# How to add an object to a html string?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to load several images by a drop action and than resizing them and adding them as a thumbnail. The resize part is very important because the images can be very large and I want to make the thumbnails small of size.

Here is my code:

```
loadingGif(drop);

for (var i=0;i<files.length;i++) {
    var file = files[i];
    var reader = new FileReader();          

    reader.onload = function(e) {
        var src = e.target.result;

        var img = document.createElement('img');            
        img.src = src;
        var scale = 100/img.height;
        img.height = 100;
        img.width = scale*img.width;    

        output.push('<div id="imagecontainer"><div id="image">'+img+'</div><div id="delimage"><img src="img/del.jpg"" /></div></div>');

        if(output.length == files.length) {
            drop.removeChild(drop.lastChild);
            drop.innerHTML += output.join('');
            output.length = 0;
        }
    }

    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
```

As you can probably tell I insert a loading gif image in my dropzone until all files are loaded (output.length == files.length). When a file is loaded I add html to an array which I will print if the load is complete. The problem is I can't seem to add the img object (I need this object to resize the image) to the html string, which seems obvious as the img is an object... So my question to you guys is: how do I do this? :)

Comment: Don't use a string at all. You should simply work with them as objects using the DOM API. Code like this `drop.innerHTML += ...` should raise warning flags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, it's bad habit to play with DOM elements as strings. You should instead use the native javascript (or the library/framework you are using) commands to create the elements and set their attributes.

For example if you have an element with id "image-container" which contains all your images, you may write.

```
var container = document.getElementById( 'image-container' );
var img = document.createElement( 'img' );

container.appendChild( img );
```

Instead of a large HTML string containing all your output, you can then have only a reference to an element containing all the other elements, and either appending it to the body as soon as all the elements have been loaded, or keeping it hidden and showing it when the loading is complete.

```
if (output.length == files.length) {
    drop.removeChild(drop.lastChild);
    drop.appendChild( container );
    output.length = 0;
}
```

Remember IDs have to be unique. There cannot be more than one element with the same ID in the same document.

Comment: Could I add the document elements to an array an append them all at once later when everything is loaded?

Comment: Yes, you could also store them all in a single array and then append them later wherever you prefer.

Comment: Avoiding strings to manipulate the DOM will lead to a much cleaner, readable, maintainable, reusable and error-free code (among the other benefits).

Answer (score 2):

HTML is parsed into elements when inserted onto the page, but that doesn't mean the two formats 1 to 1 translatable.

You could use `outerHTML` to translate the `<img>` element to a HTML string.  But this wont be efficient. You are translating an element to a string only to be parsed as an element again. Kinda sloppy.

```
"<div id='image'>"+ img.outerHTML +"</div>"
```

You could build the `<img>` tag as a string.

```
"<div id='image'><img src='"+ src +"'></div>"
```

But that starts to get hairy too.  So lastly you could append the image element after you create the other html.

```
drop.innerHTML = "<div class='image'></div>"
document.querySelectorAll('.image:last-child')[0].appendChild(img);
```

However, food for thought: when you start having this much HTML in your JS, you may want to rethink your approach a bit. It's a hard to maintain and very human error prone pattern.

Comment: Just one note... This: `document.querySelectorAll('.image:last-child')[0].appendCh...` could be rewritten as this `document.querySelector('.image:last-child').appendCh...` If you only want the first result, might as well use `querySelector` instead. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create an object with arbitrary properties, in order to hold both the image and your HTML string:

```
var result = {
   html: '<div id="imagecontainer"><div id="image">'+img+'</div><div id="delimage"><img src="img/del.jpg"" /></div></div>',
   imgTag: img
}
output.push(result);
```

And then later on when you iterate through the results array, you can access these parts as `result.html` or `result.imgTag` (changing the first part to whatever variable you've assigned the object to).

It does mean that you'd need to change your current `output.join('')` to a loop that actually iterates through the values of `output` and concatenates their `html` properties instead.  If you really wanted to avoid this, you could stick the images in a separate output-style array.  But this isn't as clean, and runs the risk of the two array contents becoming out-of-sync.  I'd stick to having two separate properties of the same object, as cleaner and better.

Comment: your object literal syntax is not valid

Comment: @jbabey bah, you're right!  Now fixed.  (I shouldn't operate heavy machinery on a Friday...)

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, there are reasons why one would avoid/choose to use strings to represent DOM elements. Also, it's a bit of a wtf moment reading code that attempts to mix both methods of representing html elements. that said, you can skip creating the image as an element in and of itself, instead inserting the appropriate string into your result(stack?).

This would have the desired scaling effect:

```
var src = e.target.result;
var imgStr = "<img src='" + src + "' height='" + 100 + "'/>";
ouput.push('<div id="imagecontainer"><div id="image">'+imgStr+'</div><div id="delimage"><img src="img/del.jpg"" /></div></div>');
```

Comment: When I just set the height and width of the image the image gets scaled indeed but the file size of the image is still very large ... Basicly I want to resize and by doing that make the file size smaller, or is that impossible?

Comment: Not possible afaik. Sure, you can use a canvas to resize the image, then use toDataURL to spit-out a resized copy of the image. the problem however, is the size-limits imposed on the length of a dataURL. I tried to cut up a sprite-sheet into smaller images. Couldn't do it with toDataURL since some tiles are too large. I had to resort to using a canvas as the source drawing element, rather than an image, as I had hoped. So, I'm of the understanding that you can't do it. There's seems to be not a lot of point anyway - the images are downloaded already and the bytes have already been burned.(??)